# Why isn't my jQuery for binding to scroll event working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create an active menu that inserts the CSS class `.active` into each list item as the user scrolls and the corresponding id is passed. I tested this in JSFiddle so I know my code is solid, but it's having no affect on the site I'm developing:

http://dev.celebrate-life.com/

Here's the jQuery:

```
  (function($) {

// Selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#menu-mainmenu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to list items
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});

})(jQuery);
```

And this is my menu structure:

```
<ul id="menu-mainmenu" class="x-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#id">List Item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have CSS for when the "active" class is applied to a list item, but it's not really relevant until I resolve the issue of applying the class to an `<li>` in the first place.

Why won't this work?

Comment: You need to add `$(document).ready(function) { ..`, what you have is just an IIFE and doesn't wait until the DOM is ready

Comment: Do you mean `$(document).ready(function() {` ? I tried wrapping the IIFE as such but am getting syntax errors for unrecognized expressions.

Comment: Replace `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);` with `jQuery(function($) { ... });`

Comment: Appreciate your help. That works in JSFiddle but on the actual site still throws syntax errors and also kills all sliders on the page. I wonder if there's a conflict with the default theme JS...